# Extracting file inside storage blob

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a 500GB VHD that is compressed into a 16GB zip file. Due to the large size of this VHD on company computers I am not able to unzip and upload the VHD to Azure Blob using AzCopy. I am in need of a way to upload the zip to Blob storage and extract the VHD to create a Managed Disk from the image.

When I saw that PowerShell was available, I figured that storage containers would be in my account similar to a hierarchy so that I would just have to navigate to the storage directory and run an unzip command or script. This appears to be incorrect and that I cannot execute commands from the PowerShell to unzip the file inside the blob storage.

Assuming that the 500GB file cannot be shrunk, and that you have to upload + extract the 16GB zip file, how could this be accomplished?

Comment: I usually use 7-zip to unzip which can be run inside a PS script.

Comment: You can use System.IO.Compression to create a stream and then upload the streamdata to the blob while unzipping it (the ZipArchive class can do this). The method that can do this (OpenEntry) is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need of a way to upload the zip to Blob storage and extract the VHD to create a Managed Disk from the image.

AFAIK, the unzipping process is not something Azure Blob Storage will do for you. You would have to handle this on your own.

You need to download the zip folder from blob storage and unzip them there and then upload files.

For a workaround, you need to upload as a zip folder to blob storage using the below commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId "Your-subscriptionid"
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "Your-storage-account" -UseConnectedAccount  
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "your-container-name" -Context $ctx -File "C:\Users\v-vsettu\Downloads\abcd.zip" -Blob "wxyz.zip"
```

Once you uploaded you can use the below Python code to upload files by unzipping the files and for sample I used a 1GB file.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import zipfile
import os
import time

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("your-connection-string")
dir_path = r"your-extractionfolder"

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test2")
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client("wxyz.zip")
#Downloading Zip to local system
with open("sample1.zip", "wb") as my_blob:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
        
    #Extracting Zip Folder to path
    with zipfile.ZipFile("sample1.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(dir_path)
        
    #Reading and uploading Files to Storage account
    fileList = os.listdir(dir_path)
    for filename in fileList:
        container_client_upload = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")
        blob_client_upload = container_client_upload.get_blob_client(filename)
        start=time.time()
        f = open(dir_path+'\\'+filename, 'r')
        byt = f.read()
        blob_client_upload.upload_blob(byt)
        end=time.time()
    print("Time taken to upload blob:", end - start, "secs")
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
Also, you can refer this [unzip a file from blob storage to File share without using windows API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/924928/unzip-a-file-from-blob-storage-to-file-share-witho)